# Store ordering in Realm

Tags: ios, uitableview, realm

I have a Realm object called `Restaurant`. I'm currently working on supporting iOS 11's drag and drop based `UITableView` reordering. Now, how would you go about storing the ordering? I wrote the function below to this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performDropWithCoordinator:(id<UITableViewDropCoordinator>)coordinator {
    NSIndexPath *destinationIndexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
    if (coordinator.destinationIndexPath != nil) {
        destinationIndexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath;
    } else {
        destinationIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:([self.tableView numberOfSections]-1)] inSection:([self.tableView numberOfSections]-1)];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < [coordinator.items count]; i++) {
        id<UITableViewDropItem> item = [coordinator.items objectAtIndex:i];

        if (item.dragItem.localObject != nil) {
            Restaurant *restaurant = item.dragItem.localObject;
            restaurant.order = destinationIndexPath.row;
            [restaurant update];
            if (self.tableView.hasActiveDrag) {
                [self.restaurants removeObject: restaurant];
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[item.sourceIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            }
            [self.restaurants insertObject:restaurant atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[destinationIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        }
    }
}
```

However, when you reorder the tableView a couple  of times, you can end up with the same integer for a couple of restaurant.order. I get what's causing this, but I don't get how I can solve this without updating *all* restaurants every time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm already has an ordered property type: [List](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html)

Using this type will preserve ordering without having to store an index order on your model.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to update *all* of the restaurants each time - you can just renumber the ones in between destination and source

Answer (score 1):

You can take a column called restaurant_order and initially set to 0. And after successfully drag and drop you have to set all items order into the realm and while getting the result use  `sortedResultsUsingProperty:@"restaurant_order"` code and set all restaurant listing.

Hope it's helped...